# Copy Class Values to Div

Tags: javascript, class

I have HTML File:

```
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value1</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value2</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value3</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value4</div>
</div>
<button onclick="Function()">Whatever</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

I'd like my function to take values from all four divs with class "um-field-value"

```
<div class="um-field-value">Value1</div>
```

And past them in Div "result"

Essentially, I want a script to simply copy values given in class um-field-value and paste it in a "result" div. I tried following:

```
function Function() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("um-field-value");
    document.getElementsById('result').innerHTML = x;
}
```

But that doesn't work at all.

I am somewhat new to coding so I am not entirely sure if it is even possible. Googled for over an hour but couldn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` gets the HTML nodes themselves but then you have to extract the values from within the HTML nodes, combine them, and set that to your result `div`. Example snippet below:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var valueNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("um-field-value"));
    var values = valueNodes.map(valueNode => valueNode.innerHTML);
    var result = values.join(' ');
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value1</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value2</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value3</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value4</div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Whatever</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` to get all the dom with this class `um-field-value` and iterate over that to get the `innerHTML`

There is a typo in your code.It is `getElementById` instead of `getElementsById`. There is an extra `s`

```js
function Function() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".um-field-value");
  let result = '';
  for (var y = 0; y < x.length; y++) {
    result += x[y].innerHTML;
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div class="um-field-area">
  <div class="um-field-value">Value1</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
  <div class="um-field-value">Value2</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
  <div class="um-field-value">Value3</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
  <div class="um-field-value">Value4</div>
</div>
<button onclick="Function()">Whatever</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. `document.getElementsByClassName` will return a `NodeList`. You need to get the `innerText` for each of the elements in that list. Depending on the browser you can either use `forEach` or a regular `for` loop to iterate over the list.

```
function Function() {
    var fieldsList = document.getElementsByClassName("um-field-value");
    var fieldValues = [];
    fieldsList.forEach(function(field) { fieldValues.push(field.innerText) });
    document.getElementsById('result').innerHTML = fieldValues.join(", ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple and readable solution that uses a loop to get the text inside each element and add it to a string. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of all elements found, so a loop is needed to get the text inside each with `textContent`.

```js
function Function() {
    var result = '';
    var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("um-field-value");
    for (var i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
        result += fields[i].textContent + '\n';
    }
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value1</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value2</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value3</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area">
    <div class="um-field-value">Value4</div>
</div>
<button onclick="Function()">Whatever</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```